# A better method than essays to measure diversity, inclusion, and equity?

Tags: job-search, university, faculty-application, early-career, diversity

I have been invited to join a scholarship/grant committee for supporting university [early career researchers](https://www.academiccareermaps.org/glossary/early-career-researcher-ecr) (ECRs). One of the aims of the panel is to implement diversity, inclusion, and equity during the selection process.

I am only aware of using an essay or biography for this evaluation. However, I personally dislike using essays/biographies because, in my opinion, they unreasonably expose the applicant's history to a person or committee who will likely become the applicant's colleague or supervisor. I would prefer a questionnaire (or similar) that focuses on facts and not narrative to evaluate the applicant's criteria in terms of diversity, inclusion, and equity.

Has anyone had experience with non-essay scoring solutions for measuring diversity, inclusion, and equity who can explain their methods and suitability?

Comment: What part of the world are you in? Practices and attitudes will vary widely.

Comment: @cag51 Would like to hear from any part of the world. What are their practices

Comment: "any part of the world" isn't very useful. In the US, there are laws about what you can ask and about the freedom to opt out.

Comment: While I understand where you're coming from, I think there is a fundamental conflict in what you're trying to achieve. One of the core goals of EDI efforts is to recognise people's individual circumstances and experiences, and judge their achievements accordingly. Any attempt to 'focus on facts' without letting people explain their personal story either (i) relies on stereotypes to assess the impact of those facts, and/or (ii) rapidly becomes worthless because there is no way to judge the sincerity of responses or differentiate between individuals.

Comment: This question focuses on DEI in selection, and there is nothing wrong with that, but I hope your committee is also thinking about how to recruit diverse candidates and how to support them once you hire them.

Comment: @Buffy Thank you Prof. I agree with you. This is a local grant and applicants are familiar to the committee. I presume we could do better rather reading their sensitive information. Hence looking for alternative methods

Comment: @avid Thank you

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thank you